# Interior of $\delta A$

Tags: general-topology

Can somebody help me out with the following question:
Let $A$ be a subset of $X$ and $\delta A=\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$. 
Proof that if $A$ is closed then the interior of $\delta A$ is empty.

Comment: It's standard to call this $\partial A$ (`$\partial A$`), rather than $\delta A$ (`$\delta A$`).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $U$ is open, then we can show that $\text{int}(\partial U)$ is empty, using the fact that $U$ and $\partial U$ are disjoint. Now apply this to $U=A^c$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is closed and $x$ is in the interior of $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c} = A \cap \overline{A^c}$. So for some non-empty open set $O$ we have $x \in O \subset A \cap \overline{A^c}$. Then $x$ is in $\overline{A^c}$, and $O$ is an open neighbourhood of it, so $O$ must intersect $A^c$, but $O \subset A$ as well. This cannot be.